# Filezilla v2 had "-config <file>". What about v3?

Tags: filezilla, command-line-arguments

Filezilla v2 had a command line parameter "-config " which allowed a quick way to choose alternative config files.
Does v3 have such a command line parameter too?

Comment: Have you tried the parameter to see if it still works?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client)) it does not. However I think you can use the new command

> filezilla -c, --site=

to connect to a specific site, that you created and configured in the Site Manager